# Flutter returns null for AppLocalization.of(context)

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

I am using Flutter to build a Web-App and I want to use the internationalization feature of flutter on my new app. I was following the [Flutter-Tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) and I try to set the app-title using the arb-file. As mentioned in the tutorial, the app_localization.dart-files are created properly for 'en' and 'de'. Yet, I get a null pointer exception in the following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate, // Post-EDIT due to croxx5f
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('de', ''),
        Locale('en', ''),
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle),
        ),
        body: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In fact, AppLocalizations.of(context) returns null.

Comment: Ok, apart from the missing AppLocalization.delegate, I noticed that I forgot to add 'intl: ^0.17.0 # Add this line'. Still after that I got the NPE, yet after fixing the title to a constant string, it vanished. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your working code as an answer to this question, please. The accepted answer does not resolve the problem, but you seem to have solved it.

Comment: The answer is to also run the flutter-commands with clean. I found out that following the documentation thoroughly avoids the problem alltogether.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should add the `AppLocalizations` in your MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp(
...
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change much, I still get the NPE...

Comment: Try to run `flutter clean && flutter pub get dependencies && flutter packages get` to trigger the codegen from the .arb

Comment: Specifically the line  `AppLocalizations.delegate,` is missing from the tutorial.

Comment: @cksrc, that's not true. Flutter did provide the example code in their documentation. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

They did mentioned this line `AppLocalizations.delegate, // Add this line`

Comment: > The AppLocalizations class also provides auto-generated `localizationsDelegates` and `supportedLocales` lists. You can use these instead of providing them manually.

Answer (score 20):

On my case, using the `Scaffold()` as `home:` of `MaterialApp()` for testing purpose caused the issue.

Once I created a Separate `HomePage()` widget and used that as
`home: HomePage()` the problem is gone.

*When I put the Scaffold(), as a direct child to MaterialApp, that treats as there were no parent contexts available with AppLocalizationDelegate, as the MaterialApp is the main context builder for all the underlying widgets.*

Bad code:

```
return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
                  body: Txt(text: AppLocalizations.of(context)?.helloWorld)
                ),
                locale: Locale('ar'),
                supportedLocales: [Locale('en'),Locale('ar')],
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                ]);
          },
        ));
```

Good code:

```
return MaterialApp(
                home: HomePag(),
                locale: Locale('ar'),
                supportedLocales: [Locale('en'),Locale('ar')],
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                ]);
          },
        ));



class HomePag extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePag> createState() => _HomePagState();
}

class _HomePagState extends State<HomePag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Txt(text: AppLocalizations.of(context)?.helloWorld),
            // Txt(text: AppLocalizations.of(context)?.translate('help'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.
Neither the accepted answer nor the "flutter clean" as suggested in accepted answer worked.

Comment: currect, that's work for me also

Comment: Oh my god this solved my problem, thank you so much. Does anybody know what's the problem here?

Comment: @Finni The context used in the Scaffold sample does not has access to the `AppLocalizations` yet, that can be solved either by creating a new widget as the author did or just wrapping the scaffold with a Builder and use the context provided by it.

Comment: Well, that works because you don't want to translate anything of the app, e.g. `MaterialApp( title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.apptitle, ...)`. How would you translate the app title?

Answer (score 4):

*Irrelevant to what the op was asking for, but:*

**If you find yourself needing to set a localized title like so:**

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    final title = l10n.myTitle;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      ...
    );
  }
```

That won't work, as you're trying to find an instance of `AppLocalization` that isn't included yet.

However, you can use the `onGenerateTitle` callback, which includes a `context` that CAN find `AppLocalization`.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateTitle: (context) {
        final l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);

        return l10n.myTitle;
      },
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Flutter 3.16.8 Dart 3.2.5

Answer (score 3):

add in l10n.yaml:

```
nullable-getter: false
```

Comment: Irrelevant to what the op is asking, but good tip none the less!

Comment: This wall use `!`

Answer (score 2):

Thats helped me. I had a CupertinoApp above MaterielApp, this override the MaterielApp and my AppLocalization.of(content) was null

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26365#issuecomment-523536339

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you followed a tutorial/course like the one from Fireship (I had the same problem because of this). There, he used a FutureBuilder where he builds another MaterialApp. You'd need to assign the same localization parameters as in the first one. Otherwise, the context object doesn't know about the AppLocalization object.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added AppLocalizations in MaterialApp of my main dart file.
The localisation became null if I called MaterialApp again on any other page.

```
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        locale: const Locale('ja'),
        supportedLocales: L10n.all,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
```

So, I had to find MaterialApp everywhere **except the main dart file** and comment out those lines, like below.

```
    return 
    // MaterialApp(
    //     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    //     home: 
        Scaffold(
           ...
        )
    // )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick solution: delay a bit for the AppLocalizations to be loaded

```
Future<bool> getDelay() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    // fix AppLocalizations.of(context) return null
    // delay a bit for the AppLocalizations to be loaded
    return true;
}
```

Then, use it in builder

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale(widget.defaultLanguage),
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            elevation: 0,
            // >>>>>> Solution here <<<<<<
            title: FutureBuilder(
              future: getDelay(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                  return const Text("Loading...");
                }
                final _ = AppLocalizations.of(context);
                return Text(_?.app_title ?? "NULL TITLE");
              },
            )),
        body: ...
     ),
   );
 }
```