# The method 'translate' was called on null. Receiver: null. Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I apologize if the question is long. I have been trying to find a solution in vain.
I am new to Flutter. I am trying to do app localization, but when I run the app, I am consistently getting this error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AuthUi(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#ff2ac]]):
The method 'translate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: translate("continue_phone")

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AuthUi file:///D:/Flutter_Projects/kits_group/lib/screens/login_screen.dart:78:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      getTranslated (package:kits_group/localization_constants.dart:54:38)
#2      AuthUi.build (package:kits_group/widgets/auth_ui.dart:29:26)
#3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4648:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
...

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/flutter (26890): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter (26890): #0      AppLocalization.load (package:kits_group/AppLocalizations.dart:21:26)
E/flutter (26890): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26890): #1      _AppLocalizationDelegate.load (package:kits_group/AppLocalizations.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (26890): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26890): #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
E/flutter (26890): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26890):
```

The load function and the translate:

```
Future load() async{
    String jsonStringValues =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lib/lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');

    Map<String, dynamic> mappedJson = json.decode(json.encode(jsonStringValues));
    _localizedValues =
        mappedJson.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
  }

String translate(String key){
    return _localizedValues[key];
  }
```

I created My getTranslated Method in the localization_constants  class like this:

```
String getTranslated(BuildContext context, String key){
  return AppLocalization.of(context).translate(key);
}
```

I am using the getTranslated method to translate the strings in my user authentication page ( class AthUi extends statelessWidget):

```
 Text(getTranslated(context,'continue_phone'), // The string are located in the json files
```

I then call the AuthUi class on my login page like this:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return Scaffold(
   body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child:Container(
              child: AuthUi(),
               ),),],),)
```

Finally the loginScreen class is called in the main class :

```
return MaterialApp(

              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              
              locale: _locale,
              supportedLocales: [
                Locale('en','US'),
                Locale('fr','FR'),
             
              ],
              localizationsDelegates: [
                AppLocalization.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales){
                for(var locale in supportedLocales){
                  if(locale.languageCode == deviceLocale.languageCode &&
                      locale.countryCode == deviceLocale.countryCode){
                    return locale;
                  }
                }
                return supportedLocales.first;
              },
              home: LoginScreen(),
            );
```

Any kind of help or proposition is very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884259

Comment: @Patrick, there seem to be no proper solution proposed on the link you recommended.